# How to fit a text with various length in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, resize

What I have is:

- a NSString which can have any length between 1 and 400 characters
- a UITableViewCell (custom layout)

I tried using an UILabel with multiple lines, set the text, and call sizeToFit. That doesn't work always, most of the time the UILabel just clips off the part of the string that doesn't fit. Also, due the varying length of the text I'd need differently sized UITableViewCells, and at the time "tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:" is called I don't know what the height will be.

So what I need is a non-scrolling UI element which is able to display text and resizes its height (the width should remain constant) to exactly fit the text. As mentioned the sizeToFit method produces mostly garbage.

Comment: Can you post the code for creating multiple lined UILabel?
It won't work until you add an option for word wrapping.

Comment: I have a custom class for my cells, so it looks like this:
`StatusCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
 [[cell statusLabel] setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
 [[cell statusLabel] setNumberOfLines:0];
[[cell authorLabel] setText:[resArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]*14+2]];
 [[cell statusLabel] setText:[resArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]*14+5]];
return cell;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use SizeWithFont: to calculate the desired height for your cell and store it in an Array so that you can return that height in HeightForRowAtIndexPath. If you need to update the text, just have a method that re-calculates the height, saves it to the array, and updates the table.  Something like:

```
 CGSize constraintSize;
 constraintSize.width = 290.0f;
 constraintSize.height = MAXFLOAT;
 NSString *text = @"YOUR TEXT"

 CGSize theSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f] constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

 NSLog(@"height: %f",theSize.height);
```

will give you the height.

Comment: Thanks, my cells have now the perfect height. Problem: the label doesn't.
What I do:
`CGRect f = [[cell statusLabel] frame];
 f.size.height = [[heightArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] floatValue];
 [[cell statusLabel] setFrame:f];`
This code is in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
The correct value is indeed in the array, I checked that, but that damn thing won't adjust its height. Well, it does sometimes, but not always, that's where I get confused. Why would it work part of the time, and partially not?

Comment: Okay, my fault, I didn't look at the log. It says: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView propert
[to be continued...]

Comment: [continue]
translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x746c5c0 h=--& v=--& H:[StatusCell:0x74560f0(160)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7445cc0 H:[UILabel:0x7442ae0(>=242)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7459d20 StatusCell:0x74560f0.trailing == UILabel:0x7442ae0.trailing + 20>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7455920 UILabel:0x7442ae0.leading == StatusCell:0x74560f0.leading + 20>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7445cc0 H:[UILabel:0x7442ae0(>=242)]>
[to be continued]

Comment: [continue]
Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.

Problem:
All the constraints (I'm using Xcode45-DP2 btw) are system generated, what means I can'T edit or remove them...

Comment: It sounds like whats happening is that the UILabel isn't wrapping text, correct? It's just drawing it off the screen?

If that is the case, you just need to set the max number of lines to 0 ([yourlabel setNumberOfLines: 0]) and set it to wordwrap ([yourlabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]). That should let it get increase the height as needed.

Comment: `StatusCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"]; [[cell statusLabel] setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping]; [[cell statusLabel] setNumberOfLines:0]; [[cell authorLabel] setText:[resArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]*14+2]]; [[cell statusLabel] setText:[resArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]*14+5]];`
I'm using Xcode45-DP2, so it's "NSLineBreakByWordWrapping" instead of "UILineBreakModeWordWrap"

Comment: I'd try setting the size of the UILabel itself as well--if it's still being cut off it's definitely possible that the label isn't tall enough to have multiple lines, even if they're allowed. Try setting the frame of the label to either the height of the cell (or, since it looks like you have more than one), some percentage of that.

Comment: actually, that was my very first attempt. Didn't work either :(

Comment: Well, I think the problem is somewhere else. I tested something, and in "tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:" i added this code:
`CGRect f = [[cell statusLabel] frame];
 f.size.height = 60;
 [[cell statusLabel] setFrame:f];`
And only one out of 29 labels had the right height afterwards, so I guess the problem is trying to set the height in that method. That means I'd need to do it before, which means I'd need to set the height if a label that's not even on screen. How?

Comment: another idea: in "tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:" I add each cell to an array, and after iOS is done drawing my tableview I loop through the array and set the height manually. Do I have a method that gets called when iOS is done drawing? Or do you have any other ideas how I should do it?

Comment: Saving each cell is probably a bad idea--assuming you're getting them by dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: then there are, in fact, only a few cells (usually one or two more than you can see at any point) and they're recycled. 

I'm not certain why resizing the labels in cellForRowAtIndexPath wouldn't be working..could you post your code?

Comment: `StatusCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
 [[cell statusLabel] setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
 [[cell statusLabel] setNumberOfLines:0];
 [[cell statusLabel] setText:[resArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]*14+5]];
 CGRect f = [[cell statusLabel] frame];
 f.size.height = [[heightArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] floatValue];
f.size.height = 60; //Just to test if at least this works
 [[cell statusLabel] setFrame:f];
[[cell authorLabel] setText:[resArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]*14+2]];
return cell;`

Comment: I'm pretty sure CGRects aren't pointers, so when you set the values of the CGRect f, It doesn't change the height of the statusLabel until you call [[cell statusLabe] setFrame:f]

Comment: I do call it, you may have overlooked it ;)
Just after my comment, end of line 6 here. (Maybe it looks like it still belongs to the comment, but that's only the crappy formatting here)

Comment: When I had autolayout issues it was because my UITableViewDelegate was forcing a smaller cell height than my UITableViewCell xib.

Answer (score 0):

This configuration should give you something simillar to what you see when you enter a loooong number in the phone app -

```
label.minimumFontSize = 4; //a very small font size
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;// change to what works for you
label.numberOfLines = 0;
```

See [lineBreakMode Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UILineBreakMode)